# Passing variables to same document Javascript / Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, anchor

i have a div tag that has a link in it. I want to click the link in the div tag but instead of loading a different page, show another div tag (sorted this with jquery)  and pass a variable from that link and print it out in that new div tag

```
<div id="link_1">
    <a href="" target="_self">Link</a>
</div>
<div id="link_1_description"></div>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#link_1_description").hide(); 
    $("#link_1").click(function() {
      $("#link_1_description ?>").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
</script>
```

any sort of answer would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(function(){
   $("#link_1_description").hide();
   $("#link_1").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var v = "I Dont Know What You Mean";
      $("#link_1_description").text(v).fadeToggle("slow");
   });
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EV7RY/1/